# llblgen pro 3 discriminator field not showing

Tags: llblgenpro

I am trying to create 'Table per entity hierarchy'  I want to set the discriminator to one of my Foreign Keys but that field does not show up in the list of available fields to pick from???

The following fields show:

PK  id (int)
isDeleted (bool)
userID fk (int)

but another FK  setup the same as userID but links to another table will not show as an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is supported, the field can't be a nullable field though, perhaps that's the problem? (and we prefer that questions are asked on our own forum as we don't actively monitor stackoverflow. )

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. I now see that the discriminator  must be assigned a value and I cannot write my own expression. I come from EOF EOModeler background and I thought I would be able to write where myField == null  as a descriminator.